# timeSpan date pc VS device

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

I have a very simple code of a date in as3:

```
var currDate:Date = new Date(Number(461624400000));
trace("currDate= "+currDate);
```

When I run this code on my PC I get this date:

> Sat Aug 18 00:00:00 GMT+0300 1984

when I run this code on my device I get this date:

> Fri Aug 17 23:00:00 GMT+0200 1984

A one day difference.

that happens only for this particular date

When I try running a similar code an JavaScript, I also got a difference when running on PC and Device.
Here the code:

```
console.log(new Date(461624400000));
```

I would be happy if someone could help me.
thanks.

Comment: The clue in the difference is the timezone values

Comment: my pc and my device are both set to the same timeZone. and it happens only for this particular date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for both AS3 and JS, actually date is set to EPOCH, hence results are identical for the both platforms.

```
var utcSeconds = 461624400000;
var date = new Date(0); // 0 sets the date to the EPOCH
date.setUTCSeconds(utcSeconds);
trace (date);
//alert (date)
```

Example with timezone shifting:

```
function timeStampDate(value) 
{
  return new Date(new Date(value).getTime() + (new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000));
};


var timestamp = 461624400000;
date = timeStampDate(timestamp);
alert (date);
```

You'll get identical hour, minute, second but with different timezone though

Comment: I tried to run your code but I still get the a one day difference in the date at the different platforms

Comment: @racheli IMHO you need exact time and don't bother about timezone, so I added new example above